A confusion about evaluating a sequential limit using the definition of the Riemann integral.
So the question is as below:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}+\frac{2}{n^2+n+2}+\frac{3}{n^2+n+3}+\cdots +\frac{n}{n^2+n+n}\right)$$
And my strategy to tackle this is to make use of the definition of definite integral of some function on the interval $[0,1]$, namely $\int_0^1 f(x) dx=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n f(\frac{k}{n}) .\frac{1}{n}$.I have tried to do estimate on the terms of the sequence to use squeeze theorem, but my estimates are a bit loose and is not enough to reach a conclusion. So can anyone provide me with some insights on this problem?

Hint: the denominators can be bounded as $$n(n+1) \leq n^2+n+k\leq (n+1)^2$$

Thanks,I did exactly the same estimates but forgot to separate out the common factor $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ and use the multiply rules for limits.
